# If $0^{\circ} \leq x < 90^{\circ}$, then simplify $\tan x\cos x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm pretty clear about the trigonometric identities but I have no idea how to apply them to this question.

> If $0^{\circ} \leq x < 90^{\circ}$, then simplify $\tan x\cos x$.

The answer is $\sin x$. But why?

Comment: Use that $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$

Answer (score 1):

The function $\tan$ is defined by the relation $\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$. Thus, multiplying by $\cos(x)$ will clear the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of $\tan x$. $$\tan x \cos x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\cos x = \sin x$$